# Can you access KeyboardEvent keys predefined keys?

Tags: javascript

Looking at the API for KeyboardEvent, there are a lot of [pre-defined values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key/Key_Values) corresponding to what `KeyboardEvent.key()` returns.

Are all of these pre-defined values accessible somehow?

Comment: What do you mean "accessible"? Like a built-in JavaScript object which holds the values, like `KeyValue.escape`? I wasn't able to find anything like that. You shouldn't enumerate an object like that anyway. Instead, you should write your code to handle only the cases where you want to take action, and ignore the rest.

Comment: Exactly, but
1) A layer of abstraction would be good if the string values change. 
2) There are scenarios for instance where regular characters should be allowed, but not navigation ones. It would be handy if there was an easy way classify keys.

Comment: Classification is a different story. It seems that you can get the code ([KeyboardEvent.code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/code)) in most browsers (looking at you, IE), upon which you could run a regex to help classify the type of key pressed. For example, pressing `A` results in `KeyA` regardless of modifier state. Pressing `1` on the number row is `Digit1` while `1` on the number pad is `Numpad1`.

Comment: Side note: Please consider updating your question with info about what you're trying to do (classifying key presses) so you can receive a specific answer to a specific question.